# Mex sparse matrix

Tags: c, matlab, sparse-matrix, mex

I created a sparse matrix in MEX using [`mxCreateSparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatesparse.html).

```
mxArray *W;
W=mxCreateSparse(n*n,n*n,xsize,mxREAL);
double *wpoint;
wpoint=mxGetPr(W);
for(p=0;p<xsize;p++)
 {
     Wpoint[(returnindex1(xi[p][0],xi[p][1])-1)*n*n + (returnindex1(xj[p][0],xj[p][1]))]=   exp(-df[p]/(SIGMAI*SIGMAI)) * exp(-dx[p]/(SIGMAJ*SIGMAJ));
 }
```

the maximum value which comes from `(returnindex1(xi[p][0],xi[p][1])-1)*n*n + (returnindex1(xj[p][0],xj[p][1]))` is `n*n*n*n` and I have created the sparse matrix of dimension `(n*n)X(n*n)`

When I display the whole matrix, some of the zero elements come as junk.
Also for large values of `n`, segmentation fault occurs at `wpoint`.

Comment: could you show more code so that we don't have to guess what else you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

The `pr` array holds `xsize` elements and you accessing the array with out of bounds indices . Hence the seg violation.

I think your fundamental problem is that you have not fully grasped how sparse matrices are stored in MATLAB. I'm not an expert on the MATLAB implementation details but my recollection is that it uses compressed column storage.

In essence there are 3 arrays as follows:

- `double pr[NZMAX]` which contains the `NZMAX` non-zero values.
- `int ir[NZMAX]` which contains the row number of each value in `pr`.
- `int jc[m]` which indexes into `pr` and `ir` identifying the first item in each of the `m` columns.

That's the executive summary, but I recommend that you read up on the details more carefully.

Comment: So my method cant be modified to work is it? the value of n can go upto 1000 so , i will have to store 3 additional arrays pr , ir , jc which will be quite time consuming. Also without going through the entire loop of for(p=0;p<xsize;p++) i wont get to know how many elements are there in the column to fill in the pr or jc array.

Comment: you don't need to store there extra arrays, matlab stores them. You need to fill them out. That's the tricky bit. What form is your matrix.

Comment: the matrix is of the order (n*n)X(n*n) and the values i assign is as shown by the formula in the above code. I dint exactly understand how MATLAB will make it on its own. In the examples folder they have manually assigned some values for each of the arrays. Please could you demonstrate how i should proceed with a code :)

Comment: I think you need to read up the matlab documentation or find a tutorial on the subject. I would recommend Tim Davis's book on sparse matrices.